# Why do we store the elment in a variable when we want to add a methode to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, methods

Like for example :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("intro"); //why do we store it in a variable?

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ..
```

Comment: There's no method in the code you posted. Also the variable `x` is never used, so this specific example is really unclear.

Comment: your first line doesn't seem to have anything to do with the second line. Unless you are doing something with the result of `document.getElementsByClassName("intro")`, the line seems unnecessary.

Comment: In general, we use variables to increase readability, and/or when we want to reuse the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are asking "why we store the element in a variable before we invoke any of its method or access any of its property. And why not directly invoke method or access property"

e.g. why `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("intro");`  and then

```
x.innerHTML = ...
```

or

```
x.appendChild(...)
```

why not

```
document.getElementsByClassName("intro").innerHTML = ...
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("intro").appendChild(...)
```

If question rephrase is correct, then answer to this is execution efficiency.

`document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementById` or any other query mechanism, where we ask document to search the element by some criteria, are costlier. Their execution time depends on document size (number of elements in it) and element location in document.

When you store the search in a variable then you can invoke multiple operation or use properties by means of that variable where re-search is not required and you save a lot of execution time.

Comment: yes that what  I meant to say... but can i invoke it without store it in a var?

Comment: Yes, you can invoke methods without storing it in a var. like document.getElementsByClassName("intro").innerHTML = ... or document.getElementsByClassName("intro").appendChild(...). But i will not recommend it. Even though you are only invoking only one method or accessing only one property, having the document searched element in a variable will also improve code readability

Comment: thanks Rahul for your participation got it .